# css : set the height of inner div just by using 'top' and 'bottom' propreties

Tags: html, css

**HTML code:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="target">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main"></div>
</div>
```

**The CSS code :**

```
.container{
    position : absolute;
    height : 100%;
    width : 100%;
    background-color : green;
}

.menu{
    position : absolute;
    top:0;
    left :0;
    height: 100%;
    width : 30%;
    background-color : orange;
}

.main{
    position : absolute;
    top:0;
    left : 30%;
    height : 100%;
    width : 70%;
    background-color : blue;
}

.target{
    position : relative;
    top : 20px;
    left : 10%;
    height: 70%;
    bottom : 100px;
    width : 80%;
    background-color : pink;
    overflow-y : auto;
}
```

**The question:**

I want to remove the '`height`' property in the '`.target`' div, so the '`height`' of the div will only depends on the '`top`' and '`bottom`' properties.

My objective is to have a fixed distance between the bottom of '`.menu`' and the bottom of '`.target`', optionally without specifying the '`height`'.

I really hope my question is clear enough, if not jst ask me, the complete code is at http://jsfiddle.net/dGkFq/3/ .

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can if you use `position:absolute`: http://jsfiddle.net/dGkFq/4/

```
.target{
    position : absolute;
    top : 20px;
    left : 10%;
    bottom : 100px;
    width : 80%;
    background-color : pink;
    display:block;
    overflow-y : auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/dGkFq/5/

**Usecase 1:**

[image]

**Usecase 2:**

[image]

```
.target{
    position : absolute;
    top : 20px;
    left : 10%;
    bottom : 100px;
    width : 80%;
    background-color : pink;
    overflow-y : auto;
}
```